Which Leray acyclicity theorems are true, and when?
I've been doing some reading around the subject and I've encountered three (arguably five) variations of the Leray acyclicity theorem given by different sources. I know three of them are true; I'm unsure of the other two, but certainly don't know where they are proven.
Let $\check{H^k}(X;\mathscr{F})$ denote the Cech cohomology of a (pre)sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ via the full colimit over all open covers ordered by refinement. Let $\mathcal{H}^k(X;\mathscr{F})$ denote the Grothendieck-derived functor sheaf cohomology.
In various places I have seen the following:
Definition:

Let $X$ be a space, $\mathscr{F}$ a sheaf on $X$. Suppose $\mathfrak{U}$ is an open cover of $X$ which contains all its finite intersections (and the emptyset) such that $\check{H^k}(W;\mathscr{F})=0$ for all $k\ge1$ and all $W\in\mathfrak{U}$. In such a case say $\mathfrak{U}$ is a good cover for $\mathscr{F}$.

Leray/Cartan acyclicity theorems (some of them at least will be true ;) ):

$(1i)$ If $\mathfrak{U}$ is good then $\mathcal{H}^\bullet(X;\mathscr{F})\cong\check{H^k}(\mathfrak{U},X;\mathscr{F})$ in all degrees
$(1ii)$ If $\mathfrak{U}$ is good and is a basis for the topology then $\mathcal{H}^\bullet(X;\mathscr{F})\cong\check{H^k}(\mathfrak{U},X;\mathscr{F})$ in all degrees
$(2i)$ If $\mathfrak{U}$ is good then $\mathcal{H}^\bullet(X;\mathscr{F})\cong\check{H^k}(X;\mathscr{F})$ in all degree, so that the canonical map $\check{H^k}(\mathfrak{U},X;\mathscr{F})\to\check{H^k}(X;\mathscr{F})$ is an isomorphism
$(2ii)$ If $\mathfrak{U}$ is good and is a basis for the topology then $\mathcal{H}^\bullet(X;\mathscr{F})\cong\check{H^k}(X;\mathscr{F})$ so that the canonical map $\check{H^k}(\mathfrak{U},X;\mathscr{F})\to\check{H^k}(X;\mathscr{F})$ is an isomorphism
$(3i)$ If $\mathfrak{U}$ is good then for any refinement $\mathfrak{V}$ of $\mathfrak{U}$, the canonical map $\check{H^k}(\mathfrak{U},X;\mathscr{F})\to\check{H^k}(\mathfrak{V},X;\mathscr{F})$ is an isomorphism
$(3ii)$ If $\mathfrak{U}$ is good and is a basis for the topology then for any refinement $\mathfrak{V}$ of $\mathfrak{U}$, the canonical map $\check{H^k}(\mathfrak{U},X;\mathscr{F})\to\check{H^k}(\mathfrak{V},X;\mathscr{F})$ is an isomorphism

$(1ii),(2ii)$ are true by spectral sequence arguments. I don't know about $(3ii)$ but it seems more plausible than $(3i)$.
Assertions $(2i)$ and $(3i)$ I have seen, $(2i)$ on our very own site, but never with proof. I would like to note that Godement proves $(2ii)$ using a basis hypothesis (I presume that's what "$\mathfrak{U}$ contient des ouverts arbitrairement petites" should mean) and does not claim $(2i)$.
A key obstruction to $(2i)$ is this; the spectral sequence argument that we would want to use would have to say that, if $\mathfrak{U}$ is good, then $\check{H^k}(X;\mathscr{H}^n(\mathscr{F}))$ vanishes for all $n\ge1,k\ge0$ where $\mathscr{H}^n(\mathscr{F})$ is the presheaf $V\mapsto\mathcal{H}^n(V;\mathscr{F})$. But then I'd need to say something about arbitrary covers, which I can't.
I've read through most of Godement, chapter $5$. I can handle the French but it's still quite dense and I may have missed something. Does anyone know authoritative references for $(2i),(3i)$ or better still does anyone know how to adapt the ideas I've presented to give proofs for them here on MSE?

A comment that may make some of these more obvious, instead of the (perhaps opaque) grothendieck spectral sequence here, for a given cover you can resolve any complex of injective sheaves into things supported on your cover using $j_!$ and $j^*$, (then spectral sequence of double complex) which shows where/how the obstructions show up, and shows functoriality under refinement more transparently.

@ChrisH I'm not sure what your double complex looks like to be honest

Sorry, I forgot the name, in the case of a double cover, it's the short exact sequence of complexes which gives the mayer vietoris LES. So ends as $\rightarrow \oplus_{U_i\cap U_j}j_!j^F^\rightarrow\oplus_{U_i} j_!j^F^\rightarrow F^*$

Sorry, only found the time now to give this a think. I think this is the "wrong" hypothesis. You have a Cartan-type hypothesis (C), whereas a Leray-type hypothesis (L) would be that the sheaf rather than Čech cohomology of elements of $\mathfrak{U}$ vanishes. In case $\mathfrak{U}$ contains the elements of a basis, (C) implies (L). The actual Leray theorem is that (L) implies conclusion (1). The (Henri) Cartan theorem is that (C) plus the basis condition implies conclusion (2) (and also conclusion (1) by Leray's theorem).

Note if $X$ is paracompact Hausdorff, the conclusions (1) and (2) are equivalent. If $X$ is hereditarily paracompact Hausdorff, the conditions (C) and (L) are equivalent. (These observations apply for example in the question you link.) I would suspect no other implications between these conditions and conclusions hold, but examples will necessarily be quite pathological and I don't have the time to tinker with them.

@Thorgott Thanks for your thoughts. Having read a few more sources such as Godement's own words, I suspect as you do that in general the basis condition should not be omitted
